# Puppet catalog run completeing but not reading my environment manifest

Tags: puppet, environment

so I have been puppet for some time and thought it would be good to start using environments. When I run puppet on my node, the catalog run appears to complete but it's not reading my manifest (I put a notify in an it's not appearing)

So on my agent, I have this in the puppet config:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter

[agent]
server = puppet.server.com
environment = live
```

When I run a puppet run I get this:

```
root@server:/var/lib/puppet/ssl# puppet agent --test --environment live
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Fact file /var/lib/puppet/facts.d/README was parsed but returned an empty data set
Info: Caching catalog for server.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1478692343'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.08 seconds
```

So it all looks good and I also see this on my master:

```
Compiled catalog for server.com in environment live in 0.01 seconds
```

However on my manifest file, I have set this to ensure it's being read:

```
notify {'hey there i hit this env':}
```

Here is the environment setup:

```
root@puppet:/etc/puppet/environments/live# ls
manifests  modules
```

I have even tried using an environment.conf and setting the manifest manually, neither this or having a manifests folder in the environment appear to work. The manifest is currently named site.pp, but has been called live.pp also.

Now, here is my puppet conf on the master:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
certname = puppet.support.com
dns_alt_names = puppet.support.com
server = puppet.support.com
environmentpath = $configdir/environments

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
```

Does anyone have any idea why the environment manifest is not being read? For clarity, it's below:

```
cat site.pp

notify {'hey there i hit this env':}

node 'server.com' {
    notify {'hey there i hit this node':}
}
```

Comment: What version of Puppet? If you 'just started' using environments, then I would assume this is a very old version, since not using them was a warning starting in 3.5 and an error starting in 3.7, both of which have long been unsupported.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 3.8 is being used.

Comment: ii  puppet                         3.8.7-1puppetlabs1

Comment: So installed from a package and not from gem? Open source 3.8 has been a long time ago for me so I had to doublecheck documentation, but something that really stands out for me is `environmentpath = $configdir/environments` on your master's `puppet.conf`. Try setting that to the absolute `environmentpath = /etc/puppet/environments` (or even removing it entirely and force it to use the default setting), which would explain why the agent is only doing the `basemodulepath` and not the environment path. What happens when you update that setting on the master and restart services?

Comment: I have tried removing it, hashing it and using full path. No change. It was installed via dpkg using puppet labs latest at the time (long time ago now)

Comment: Environments open up a can of worms.  There are legitimate uses for them, but it's "good to start using environments" only if they solve a *bona fide* problem for you in a way that doesn't create significant new problems.  The ways most people seem to apply environments don't do that.

Comment: Ah right, the reason I started using them is because I started to use puppet forge modules in modules, then my own modules in localmodules. And puppet told me module_path was depreciated and to use environments

Comment: I should have said that using *multiple* environments opens up a can of worms.  Unless you have good reason to do otherwise, I suggest using only the default environment, "production".  Don't throw another (e.g. "live") into the mix, not even if you assign all nodes to that environment.  That's unlikely to be a solution to the specific problem you're presently grappling with, however.

Comment: I suspect that you are running into trouble with the environment cache.  After changing or adding manifests, it's a good idea to restart the master to invalidate the environment cache.

Comment: Note also that the deprecation warning you received is about the form of your Puppet configuration -- [config-file environments *vs*. directory environments](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/reference/environments.html#directory-environments-vs-config-file-environments) -- not about changing to which environment(s) your nodes are assigned.

Comment: Thanks John, I have changed the environment to production, ensured the var is set on the agent
root@v-internet:~# echo $FACTER_environment
production

And rebooted both machines, same issue.

Comment: Changing /manifests/production.pp to /manifest/site.pp has fixed the problem :S This is fine for now, but if I ever bring in a dev environment I will have issues

Comment: I managed to get this working, not entirely sure how.

Think it was ultimately a cache issue as you said, so if you want to submit that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I suspect that you are running into trouble with the environment cache. After changing or adding manifests, it's a good idea to restart the master to invalidate the environment cache. – John Bollinger Nov 9 '16 at"